# Mongo replica node with docker

Tags: node.js, mongodb, docker

I have setup a Mongo Primary node with docker using docker image https://hub.docker.com/_/mongo/. 
Now I wish to add replica node in my current setup using docker only.
Can anybody help me with this?

Answer (score 3):

You could check a guide like "[Deploy a MongoDB Cluster in 9 steps Using Docker](https://medium.com/@gargar454/deploy-a-mongodb-cluster-in-steps-9-using-docker-49205e231319#.cl770gmmp)", but that involve multiple working docker servers.

It uses a key file key file to be used on all nodes (`openssl rand -base64 741 > mongodb-keyfile`) for [internal authentication](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/security-internal-authentication/#internal-auth-keyfile).
That allows to create an admin user, which then adds the replica servers:

```
docker run \
--name mongo \
-v /home/core/mongo-files/data:/data/db \
-v /home/core/mongo-files:/opt/keyfile \
--hostname="node1.example.com" \
--add-host node1.example.com:${node1} \
--add-host node2.example.com:${node2} \
--add-host node3.example.com:${node3} \
-p 27017:27017 -d mongo:2.6.5 \
--smallfiles \
--keyFile /opt/keyfile/mongodb-keyfile \
--replSet "rs0"
```

On each replica, you initiate and then check the config:

```
 rs.initiate()
 rs.conf()
```

Back to node 1, you declare the replica:

```
rs0:PRIMARY> rs.add("node2.example.com")
rs0:PRIMARY> rs.add("node3.example.com")
```

Comment: Thanks @VonC I will test this today and put my comments here.

Answer (score 0):

There are number of steps to solve this problem with docker:

1. switch to db admin

> use admin

2. Create a new site admin user

> ```
> db.createUser( {
>          user: "siteUserAdmin",
>          pwd: "password",
>          roles: [ { role: "userAdminAnyDatabase", db: "admin" } ]
>        });
> ```

3. Create a new root user

> db.createUser( {
>         user: "siteRootAdmin",
>         pwd: "password",
>         roles: [ { role: "root", db: "admin" } ]    });

4. We can now initiate the replica set:

> ```
>    rs.initiate()
>     {
>              "info2" : "no configuration explicitly specified -- making one",
>              "me" : "node1.example.com:27017",
>              "info" : "Config now saved locally.  Should come online in about a minute.",
>              "ok" : 1
>     }
> ```

5. Verify the initial replica & check the configuration :

> ```
> rs0:PRIMARY> rs.conf()
> {
>         "_id" : "rs0",
>         "version" : 1,r
>         "members" : [
>               {
>                   "_id" : 0,
>                   "host" : "node1.example.com:27017"
>               }
>         ]
> }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

I built an image which provide env variables for replication and sharded cluster:
[khezen/mongo](https://hub.docker.com/r/khezen/mongo/)

replica set is initialized automatically.